# Why is this form being returned as invalid (uploading a text file)

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to develop a minimal text file uploading example. This is what I 
currently have. Whenever I submit my form with a selected file its validation fails.

This is the Form

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

This is the View

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UploadFileForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                file = form.cleaned_data["file"]
                .....
                .....
        else:
            form = UploadFileForm()
        return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the template : upload.html

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form|crispy }}
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am aware there are a couple of examples out there however I would like to know what might be wrong with my code. Whenever I submit my file my form validation fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using FileField in form there has to be a request.FILES to get the files from the form.

```
form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
```